# Add button in favourite/ignored tags are sliced off

Tags: bug, design

Doesn't look quite right to me! The add button is cut off near the right end. Can anyone reproduce? This is in the sidebar.

[image: screenshot]

I use the latest version of Chromium on Gentoo.

Comment: Repro with Chrome 40 when I change increase the zoom to 110%

Comment: Are you zoomed in/out? Does this happen on other browsers?

Comment: No repro in IE11